# jQuery: dialog not opening second time properly

Tags: jquery

I have created one jQuery dialog. Below is the Ajax function where I have created that.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/StaffManageCertifications/GetExamCodesAndCategory/",
    type: "Post",
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        debugger;
        $('#divExamCodesCategory').html(data);
        $("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 700,
            height: 610,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            draggable: true,
            title: 'Add Exam Code/Category'
        });
        $("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog("open");
        $('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();
        $('#divProcessImage').css({
            "display": "none"
        });
    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {
        ErrorMessageStaff(req.responseText);
        $('#screen').css({
            "display": "block",
            "width": "",
            "height": ""
        });
        $('#divProcessImage').css({
            "display": "none"
        });
    }
});
```

Now, I have placed two buttons(Ok and Cancel) on that div = divExamCodesCategory.

and written below line of code to destroy this dialog everytime, when I close it.

```
$("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog("destroy");
```

now, when I am opening it second time, 
on first click - it doesn't show dialog.
on second click  - it does show dialog but without the data. empty dialog.

Also, it is not coming in the center of the screen. It drops down to the bottom of the screen. below is the position style for this dialog.

```
.ui-dialog {
    padding: 0em !important;
    position: fixed !important;
}
```

Any help on this appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a http://jsFiddle.net ?

Comment: Close the dialogue rather than destroy it

Comment: I can try..Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: James, I tried that too. But still not working. I tried remove also. Thanks

Comment: @gdoron - I have created this fiddle - I could not make it working but placed all the code in that. Please check this. - http://jsfiddle.net/Q35AD/

Comment: How are you managing the cancel button? This is working for me. Take a look to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KAdSJ/)

Comment: Anu, it could be the problem with Ajax call. I have created this dialog in that , and you have done it in document.ready. I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found below Solution to this problem: hope this help someone.. :)

Managed to solve the issue, the issue was that the program was repeatedly creating unnecessary div's whenever $("import_box_dialog").dialog() was called. And since the $ operator returns u all the div's matching a given condition, i.e. ID in this case, hence the content did not become visible, which i think made it confused, there are two ways to solve it:

Remove the Div manually by calling

`$("import_box_dialog").remove()`

This would however remove all the other Div's inside the dialog div
    Use a variable to track the div used for the dialog box, since I am using jquery classes, I use it for the static variable. Thus this way, it tracks the dialog, and always creates the dialog on the same div.

I suppose jquery applies a lot of class styles, due to which there is ambiguity in the selection of the proper div, and I guess using a static variable solves it.

Answer (score 5):

If you intend to destroy the dialog every time it's closed, that needs to be done in the dialog's close handler:

```
$(...).dialog({
    ...,
    close: function() {
        $(this).dialog('destroy');
    }
});
```

As it stands, if your (unshown) `destroy` call is immediately after this AJAX call as you've described it'll actually happen immediately because the AJAX call is *asynchronous* and finishes straight away.

p.s. instead of using `$.css({'display': 'none'})`, just use `.hide()`

Answer (score 0):

(Creating one dialog and reusing it) is good approach and vice-versa.
//you are creating new dialog every time,check if it already created or not
if not, then create and open else open previously created dialog

```
 if (!$("#divExamCodesCategory").hasClass('ui-dialog')) { //check if alredy created
// it is not initialized yet
        $("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog({ autoOpen: false,
                width: 700,
                height: 610,
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                draggable: true,
                title: 'Add Exam Code/Category'

            });
        //initialized
    }
//open dialog
    $("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog("open");// after creation
```

Comment: the OP is destroying it everytime

Answer (score 0):

First. you must move this code outside the ajax call.

```
$("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog({ autoOpen: false,
    width: 700,
    height: 610,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    title: 'Add Exam Code/Category'

});
```

Put it in this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog({ autoOpen: false,
        width: 700,
        height: 610,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: true,
        title: 'Add Exam Code/Category'
    });
});
```

Change the success call into:

```
success: function (data) {
    debugger;
    $('#divExamCodesCategory').html(data);
    $("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog("open");
    $('a.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').remove();
    $('#divProcessImage').css({ "display": "none" });
},
```

And when you want to close. Do not destroy the object. Just close it

```
$("#divExamCodesCategory").dialog("close");
```

For the css. Do not fixed the position of the dialog. It's by default on the center screen. You might want to adjust the height and width, but leave the position.

Comment: I disagree, it's perfectly acceptable to create and destroy dialog boxes on the fly - the overhead is negligible, and it requires less state to be maintained.

Comment: I cannot make this out of Ajax call, as I am getting data from the database to fill in this dialog. So I am calling this dialog on success of that data. Is there any reason of not placing that inside Ajax ?